# Combining legoes

Tags: combinations

I have this question where I get

- lego $4$ inch
- lego $6$ inch

I want the length of $48$ inches. How would the $2$ lego be combined to get $48$ inches? The equation is 
$$
4a + 6b = 48 $$
which has the solutions

- $a=0, b=8$
- $a=3, b=6$
- $a=6, b=4$
- $a=9, b=2$
- $a=12, b=0$

So it was $5$ difference way you can achieve $48$ inches 
Now the question is, in how many ways can you line the lego ?

Comment: Presumably each of the "4 inch" lego are otherwise identical and can only be put in a space in the line in effectively one way, similarly for each of the 6 inch lego (*Pedantic nitpick, the plural of lego is lego without the `s`, not legos*).  Now, for each of your cases you found, count the number of orderings of the corresponding number of 4 inch lego and 6 inch lego using binomial coefficients.  For instance, with three $4$ inch lego and six $6$ inch lego, you have nine spaces total and so $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to choose which of the spaces are used by the $4$ inch lego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very awkwardly stated!  In the first place, we **don't** have "two legos", we have two **kinds** of legos!  The problem is to find how many of each kind we can use.

Then you are seeking non-negative integers, a and b, such that 4a+ 6b= 48.  The first thing I would do is divide through by 2:  2a+ 3b= 24.  Now "2" and "3" are prime so, by the Euclidean algortihm, we know there must exist integers (not necessarily positive), a and b, such that 2a+ 3b= 1.  In fact, that's obvious- 3- 2= 1.  Now multiply by 24:  3(24)- 2(24)= 2(-24)+ 3(24)= 24.  That is, a= -24, b= 24 is a solution.  But then, a= -24+ 3k, b= 24- 2k is also a solution for every integer, k:  2(-24+ 3k)+ 3(24- 2k)= -48+ 6k+ 72- 6k= 24.

We want **non-negative** integers so we need to choose k so that both a= -24+ 3k and b= 24- 2k are positive.  3 divides into 24 8 times so [tex]k\ge 8[/tex] will make a non-negative.  2 divides into 24 12 times so [tex]k\le 12[/tex] will make b non-negatifve.

The solutions are

- (k= 8) a= -24+ 3(8)= 0, b= 24- 2(8)= 8;
- (k= 9) a= -24+ 3(9)= 3, b= 24- 2(9)= 6;
- (k= 10) a= -24+ 3(10)= 6, b= 24- 2(10)= 4;
- (k= 11) a= -24+ 3(11)= 9. b= 24- 2(11)= 2; and
- (k= 12) a= -24+ 3(12)= 12, b= 24- 2(12)= 0.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

In the case $a=0, b=8$ you have only one way (if the lego pieces are identical), think about it as putting eight letter *b*s in a row
$$
bbbbbbbb
$$
can be done only one way as long as the lego are identical. If not then you can say that you can choose from $8$ different one for the first place, $7$ for the second and so on giving $1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot 8=8!$

In the case $a=3, b=6$ you have to arrange three *a*s and six *b*s, the question is in how many different words you can create using these letters
$$
aaabbbbbb
$$
is one of them. Once again we have to ask whether these are *a*s and *b*s are indentical in between themselves. If they are all different you  get $9!$ otherwise 
you can swap the first and the second *a* to get
$$
aaabbbbbb.
$$
In fact all the *a*s and *b*s are swappable and you have to sort of *remove* these, by dividing by all the different ways of ordering them giving you
$$
\frac{9!}{3!\cdot 6!}
$$
where $3!$ is all the ways to order the *a*s and $6!$ is all the ways to order the *b*s.

Hope this helped

You can further read up on [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)